# 403 Access Denied: BigQuery: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials

Tags: google-bigquery, google-api, service-accounts

Attempting to use BigQuery client library to query from BigQuery table, but getting 403 error on Drive credentials.

Looked around already.  Using service account as authentication.  Can query from tables that are not connected to external sheets just fine.  Problem is only with tables/views that are externally connected to a google sheet.  Shared service account with the sheets, under viewer permission.  Absolutely sure that the service account has full viewer access to all sheets it needs, and all permissions on Google Cloud end.  Suspect it might be because of the format of the google sheet.  The Google Sheet is composed of multiple tabs, but only one tab corresponds to actual BQ.  Service account still has access to overarching sheet.

Comment: Please edit you question and include your code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.